# Will phone of global market will have better coverage than others?

Tags: carriers

I have LG V20 (H990DS), it's global market's phone. Also there are AT&T, Sprint, Verizon. And I noticed that all models have different frequency bands. Is that mean that my phone will work better around the world and others are fixed to certain regions? If yes, other phones can be unlocked by rooting or something like that to work the same as "Global" phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .... my phone will work better around the world and others are fixed to certain regions?

In theory, yes. That's the purpose of a *global* phone (also called international phone)

> ....other phones can be unlocked by rooting or something like that to work the same as "Global" phone?

No, since it requires changes at hardware (modem) and corresponding drivers. You can't change hardware by rooting

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, I noticed that H990DS has 16 4G bands and H990N (of Hong Kong) has 15. Does it mean that 4G will work in higher coverage in China on H990N than my H990DS?

Comment: Maybe is better to count how many bands phone supports and check if it works in native country. European variant with 17 bands would probably be even better than global with 16.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105002/discussion-between-vasik988-and-beeshyams).

Comment: @beeshyams It could be useful to keep in mind that some OEMs (e.g. Samsung) allow for carriers to only preload some apps, instead of locking the device altogether - in that case, the phone _might_ be usable internationally.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman- Thanks, yes, useful. I wasn't aware